# Tag synonym: glacier -> amazon-glacier

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There were only five questions tagged with [glacier](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/glacier), so, going with the AWS tag convention, I created [amazon-glacier](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-glacier) and re-tagged these five questions.

Please synonymize [glacier](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/glacier) to [amazon-glacier](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-glacier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems sensible to me. I doubt we're going to talk about the other kind of glaciers on Server Fault.